# Php queries aren't working

Tags: php, mysql

I have been literally running this code for days. I have tested my query in the database in phpmyadmin and it works and my connection to the database says its connected but when I run the code its not working. Any ideas?

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
ORDER BY customer.CUST_LAST_NAME
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
require_once('./connection.php')
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <?php
    //query
    $resultset = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer.CUST_LAST_NAME;");
    echo $resultset->num_rows;
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should see errors come up. Perhaps "error reporting" is turned off. Can you turn it on? Also, Im assuming `$mysqli` is coming from `'./connection.php'`, can you provide the code that resides there?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. provide `connection.php` code and hide the database credentials

Comment: Check your error log. You may get more information about what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This code has been adjusted to suit your need. it will show the **row count number** that you want as well as the **customer last name**. if it solve your problem, you can mark it as correct answer. if it does not ping me here and i will assist you further.

**change the database credentials to yours**

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
//require_once('./connection.php')




$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
         $dbuser = 'root';
         $dbpass = '';
         $dbname = 'angular';
         $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

         if(! $conn ) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
         }
         echo 'Connected successfully<br>';


?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <?php
    /*query
    $resultset = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customer.CUST_LAST_NAME;");
echo $resultset->num_rows;*/



$sql = 'SELECT * from customer order by customer.CUST_LAST_NAME';
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo $result->num_rows;

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "<br><br>customer lastName: " . htmlentities($row["CUST_LAST_NAME"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). "<br>";
            }
         } else {
            echo "0 results";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain further the problem with the original code and what makes your code better? As far as I can see, it looks a bit strange to use both the OOP approach and the functional one

Answer (score -1):

You always need to do error handling as below example from PHP documentation.

Like this you can debug the issue, that is either:

- it cannot connect to the database
- there is an error in you query syntax

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```